# Convert multi columns into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to come up with select statement that will take multiple columns and put them into a single column For example, if I have data like the below:

```
id  d1      d2
1   R04.0   
1   Z00.129 Z13.220
2   Z00.129 Z68.36
2   Z23 
3   Z23
```

I want the data to look like this

```
id  column 1
1   R04.0
1   Z00.129
1   Z13.220
2   Z00.129
2   Z23
2   Z68.36
3   Z23
```

I tried looking at pivot tables, but I don't think that is what I am looking for. I can probably write a cursor, but that seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Because the other answers are either incomplete or overly complex, here is another alternative.

Note I am assuming that `d1` is never null/empty but that `d2` might be and that you want your results ordered by `id` and `col1`

```
select id, d1 col1
from MyTable

union all

select id, d2 col1
from MyTable
where d2 is not null

order by id, col1;
```

Comment: Good one, thanks! I thought it was a dialect and may not work in some databases, and I checked Oracle, Postgres, SQLite, MySQL, and SQLServer, it works in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION ALL` should do the trick.

```
SELECT id, column1 = d1 FROM data WHERE d1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, column1 = d2 FROM data WHERE d2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, column1
```

Comment: OP appears to want the id in the result set, and have it ordered.

Comment: Fixed as suggested.

Comment: The `column1 = d1` may not work in some database (Oracle and MySQL don't work), use the general form like `d1 as column1` or just `d1 column1` would be a better idea

Comment: Yes, but this was posted with a sql-server tag. It's a style preference. I've found the `name = expression` form somewhat more readable, but you are correct that the standard `expression AS name` is almost(?) universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option to dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually using Dynamic SQL

Notice we just have to exclude the column/key `ID`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b44e5a8c72d49e4629715beccd9527fd)**

```
Select A.id 
      ,Column1 = B.Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply OpenJSON( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) B
 Where [Key] not in ('id')
```

**Results**

```
id  Column1
1   R04.0
1   Z00.129
1   Z13.220
2   Z00.129
2   Z68.36
2   Z23
3   Z23
```

**EDIT - If you want to see column name as well**

```
Select A.id 
      ,ColName  = B.[key]
      ,ColValue = B.Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply OpenJSON( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) B
 Where [Key] not in ('id')
```

**Results**

```
id  ColName ColValue
1   d1      R04.0
1   d1      Z00.129
1   d2      Z13.220
2   d1      Z00.129
2   d2      Z68.36
2   d1      Z23
3   d1      Z23
```